# <p> text aligns left, but I need it on top of an image background in a <div> class

Tags: html, css

I'm having a nightmare trying to get a small piece of text to sit over an image, centered on my page. The closest I've managed is the text box is now slightly right of center.

I'm trying to accomplish this through using a Div class with the image as the background, with the text inside of a paragraph within the div class "TEST". I'm doing it this way as I later want to animate it on hover, but for the moment I'm just trying to get the text to sit on top of the image!

I thought **margin: auto 0**; would help, but it caused even more problems so I removed it and tried **display: inline;** instead which got me a bit closer. Now I'm all out of ideas...

Here's the p CSS:

```
p  {    
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
    padding: 2px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

Here's the Div CSS, with its class:

```
div { 
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
}

.TESTimage {
      background-image: url("https://eccentric.productions/assets/roundlogo");
      background-size: 100px; 
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      height: 100px;
 }
```

And finally, the relevant section of HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="TEST">
        <p>
            Writing
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Many thanks to anyone who can help me out, I've used Stack Overflow for years but this is the first time I've needed to post a question. You folks do an amazing job!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? :)

Comment: So this has "Writing" centered: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ublzF. Are you wanting the text ABOVE the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must remove `position: absolute;` in p tag i remove `background-position: center center;` in .test class to easy view. Here html code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p  {    
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
     background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
    padding: 2px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;

    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

div { 
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    }

.TEST {background-image: url("https://eccentric.productions/assets/roundlogo");
      background-size: 100px; 
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

      height: 100px;

      }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="TEST">
    <p>
    Writing
    </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this help

Comment: This was the closest to what I was looking for, thank you! 

In the end though I found an alternative (and nicer) way to do what I was looking for, courtesy of this blog: http://geekgirllife.com/animate-text-over-images-on-hover-without-javascript/  


Many thanks all who posted answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant say margin: 0 auto or text-align: center to absolute position you have to use left or right. I would give some width to the p like 60px and left: calc(50% - 30px);

```
p  {    
background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
padding: 2px;
line-height: 28px;
position: absolute;
width: 60px;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
left: calc(50% - 30px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to achieve? 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cCbtA

I have added a border around the image just so it's easier to see.

Sorry if I have misunderstood what you wanted, but hope it helps!

HTML

```
 <div class="test">
    <p>
        Writing
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .test {
  background-image: url("https://eccentric.productions/assets/roundlogo");
  background-size: 100px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }


.test p {
text-align: center;
background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
margin:0;
color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want text to just sit over top of your image this might be what your after? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: If you are giving only a link, why don't you make it a comment rather than an answer?